# What will be the output 012/2 in PHP?

Tags: php

What will be the output of this expression ?

```
$a = 012;
$b = $a / 2;

var_dump($b);
```

I got the answer (int) 5 Please anyone suggest me how this is calculate ?

Comment: 012 is `10` in base-8 (octal)

Answer (score 3):

When you use a leading `0` in `012`, you're actually using [octal notation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.syntax). That means, that this is `12` number but as an octal number.

So`012` is actually `8+2`, which is `10`  as a decimal number.